# read number of characters in a fixed width file before processing the data file

Tags: r, fixed-width

I have a fixed width file that is split into 8 parts that need to be Row binded together. The problem is that 5 of the 8 parts have an extra column that needs to be removed.

I have a numeric vector of the correct column widths, and incorrect column widths

I'd like to loop through the files, and if it has the correct number of characters in a line (177), then to use the correct column width, otherwise use the incorrect column width

I've tried using

```
sum(nchar(read_fwf(file,fwf_widths(correct_vector)))
```

but when I pull in the file using `read_fwf` (and `read.fwf` for that matter), it formats the columns and the number of characters in a column is not equal to the number of characters in the nonformatted version. For instance, instead of 177 characters, it shows 135 due to missing padded zeros or NA's not counting.

So I'm looking for a way to read the file and count the number of characters in the first line without formatting.

Comment: Deleted the last one I thought. I don't know how to make a reproducible example since it's using a fixed width data file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use readLines to read the first line of each file and check its length using `nchar`.

```
filelist <- dir(pattern='txt$')
for (i in filelist) {
    if (nchar(readLines(i, n=1) == 177)
        print('correct')
    else
        print('incorrect')
}
```